# Cant open pending orders

Tags: orders, backend, magento2.2.6

Hello i have problem with loading pending orders from backend 
Im pressing view button and it trying to load the page but after a while i get 500 internal server error 
 any suggest??

Comment: Enable developer mode and check the issue.

Comment: well im in production mode and we got ppl online :/

Answer (score 1):

Please check `var/log/system.log` and `var/log/exception.log` and check your server `log /var/log/nginx/error.log (for nginx server)` `/var/log/nginx/error.log (for apache server)`

And try to solve yourself or paste your error description here, so someone can help your issue.

Comment: none error about this...